# VLOOKUP not applying to all the rows through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am applying VLOOKUP to one column using 2 sheets. The code works but it is applied only in one cell. I want to apply to all the cells below header.
Below is my code which I am trying to execute:

```
ESheet.Range("C2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2, Roles!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)"
```

Comment: you onla put the formula in one cell. I would copy it to all other cells in the next step

Comment: Can you help me how to drag it to all cells till end

Comment: No need to drag the formula. It can be put in all rows at once. Please see my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code, please:

```
Sub VlookupAlColumn()
 Dim ESheet As Worksheet, lastR As Long
 'Set ESheet = ActiveSheet 'only for me, for testing reason
 lastR = ESheet.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 ESheet.Range("C2:C" & lastR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2, Roles!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)"
End Sub
```

Comment: @CLR: I would not say like that... `Cells.Rows.Count` returns the same `Long` variable value for **all sheets**... So, using the active sheet would never create a problem. Am I Wrong?

Comment: lastR = ESheet.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row  --> Just a little tweak, referred column A which is existing column with no empty rows

Comment: @Nipen Mahajan: Correct... Maybe, better to declare another `Long` variable and make it `lastRA`. Only in order to not mix them by mistake, when you have more such cases which are not strictly consecutive like code lines.